# How to use a Gitlab Merge Request to finish a release/hotfix branch using Gitflow?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, git-flow, merge-request

So our company is using [Gitflow](https://files.programster.org/tutorials/git/flows/git-flow.png). Can't currently change that. I have looked into [github-flow](https://files.programster.org/tutorials/git/flows/github-flow.png) and [gitlab-flow](https://files.programster.org/tutorials/git/flows/gitlab-flow.png), but we can't currently move to a different model.

When finishing a *hotfix* or *release branch*, right now we don't use merge requests, but manually use gitflow to locally merge the branches into master/dev/release.

Is there a supposed way of finishing a branch using *merge requests* in *Gitlab*? We'd like to go protect the master and dev branches from pushes. It's just safer to let gitlab handle the actual merging.

I'd've opened an issue on gitlab directly, but I'm not actually sure where.

Edit: I also thought about making two Merge Requests in Gitlab, but that can't be the way either.

Comment: If I understand the *question* correctly, you want to delete a feature-branch were changes are made you created with *gitflow*, to push the changes not in the original branch, right?

Comment: I want to finish a release-branch created with gitflow, therefore merging it into master and develop. Currently we do that locally using git flow command, but I'd prefer to completely protect dev/master from pushes and have Gitlab handle the merging.

Comment: What about this? [GitLab-Flow](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2014/09/29/gitlab-flow/)

Comment: That is why I wrote that I can't currently chagne that ;) - I'd sure like to change to a more agile flow, but we have to stay on the default gitflow. Tried getting people's minds open for another kind of flow, but didn't work. Still Gitlab should have a way of supporting the default gitflow.